# why the chart I created could not be interactive? (live graph in matplotlib from arduino)

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, arduino

[image]

I made a graph of an arrow that rotates correspond with the data obtained from the rotary encoder. Every time I turn the knob rotary encoder, it will bring a new chart. In fact, I just want to display **a graph** that showing the rotation of an arrow at any time. Where is the error code that I create?

```
%matplotlib qt
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s=[]
plt.ion()
def up():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, polar=True)
    ax1.set_rmax(2.0)
    ax1.set_theta_zero_location("N")
    ax1.set_rticks([])
    plt.title('Angle \n')
    plt.rc('grid', color='black', linewidth=1, linestyle='-')
    ax1.set_xticklabels(['U', 'BL', 'B', 'BD', 'S', 'TG', 'T', 'TL'])
    plt.arrow(ino, 0, 0, 1.55,alpha = 0.75, width = 0.01,ec = 'black', fc = 'blue', lw = 1.25)

while True:
    ino=float(serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600).readline()[10:])/180.*np.pi
    s.append(ino)
    up()
    plt.pause(.000001)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have one single figure, you should create only one single figure instead of one figure per update.

In the update function, you then only remove the old arrow from the axes and plot a new one.

```
%matplotlib qt
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s=[]
plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, polar=True)
ax1.set_rmax(2.0)
ax1.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax1.set_rticks([])
plt.title('Angle \n')
plt.rc('grid', color='black', linewidth=1, linestyle='-')
ax1.set_xticklabels(['U', 'BL', 'B', 'BD', 'S', 'TG', 'T', 'TL'])
arrow = plt.arrow(0, 0, 0, 1.55,alpha = 0.75, width = 0.01,ec = 'black', fc = 'blue', lw = 1.25)

def up(ino):
    arrow.remove()
    return plt.arrow(ino, 0, 0, 1.55,alpha = 0.75, width = 0.01,ec = 'black', fc = 'blue', lw = 1.25)

while True:
    ino=float(serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600).readline()[10:])/180.*np.pi
    s.append(ino)
    arrow = up(ino)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(.000001)

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I am sorry, your code is still error =               list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: I can run the code without problem. Have you changed it compared to my answer?

Comment: ![Screen Shoot of Plot](http://tinypic.com/r/2my3of4/9). yes, at first, I just tried to replicate some of the code that you created. But, when I imitated all your code, it appears that the output is read unchanged (stays at number 12).
Note: I changed the code in arduino of previously produces an output "Position: 12" to be "12" so that the code that now there is no list slicing ([10:]). In addition, I now receive the output from arduino is angle value, so, I delete  (ino / 180. * np.pi) in my python code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I am try to add new variable(inoS) in your(@ImportanceOfBeingErnest) code. I don't know why it work, but it solve my problem... Do you know why it work?

```
%matplotlib qt
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from drawnow import *

s=[]
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, polar=True)
ax1.set_rmax(2.0)
ax1.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax1.set_rticks([])
plt.title('Angle \n')
plt.rc('grid', color='black', linewidth=1, linestyle='-')
ax1.set_xticklabels(['U', 'BL', 'B', 'BD', 'S', 'TG', 'T', 'TL'])
plt.ioff()
arrow = plt.arrow(0, 0, 0, 1.55,alpha = 0.75, width = 0.01,ec = 'black', fc = 'blue', lw = 1.25)
def up(inoS):
    arrow.remove()
    return plt.arrow(-inoS/180.*np.pi, 0, 0, 1.55,alpha = 0.75, width = 0.01,ec = 'black', fc = 'blue', lw = 1.25)

while True:
    ino=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)
    inoS=float(ino.readline())
    print inoS
    s.append(inoS)
    arrow=up(inoS)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(.000001)
plt.show()
```